# Documentary on number theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Can anyone suggest documentaries on Number theory ? Looking to show it to high school and undergrads

Thanks

Comment: Look at the [_Mathematics Illuminated_](http://www.learner.org/resources/series210.html) series ([Magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) link: magnet:?xt=urn:btih:e7d9f0ab4e6bf8e9b7cadf37d0e6ba3285172352 ). Individual segments of that series can also be found on YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could argue Paul Erdos' [N is a Number](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wN4yLPPvRBg)
 
is more a biographical documentary than a mathematical one, and you'd be right, but still it's something beautiful that I'd recommend to any person (mathematically driven or not).

Also, it might not be contemporary enough to attract young audiences. In this respect you might want to move away from documentaries and towards other mediums like youtube. There are certain youtube channels (upfront I would say [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile)
) that make short entertaining mathematical videos for a general audience.